# Include a connection to Wordpress within OpenCart

Tags: php, wordpress, pdo, opencart, opencart2.x

I wonder if it is possible to include a independent query to a WordPress database within an OpenCart shop.

I tried a code like this in order to simply display one specific post onto a template:

```
$wpbridge = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$base, $user, $pass, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8'));
$wpquery = $wpbridge -> query(" [...] ");
$wpcontent = $wpquery -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

But I get this kind of error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'could not find driver' in [...]\home_test.inc on line 1
PDOException: could not find driver in [...]\home_test.inc on line 1
```

I presume my connection attempt collides with the main one (settled in `system>library>db>mpdo.php`) used by the shop.

Does anybody know a possible way to sidestep this constraint (for using temporary a second connection)?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't really recommend establishing a database connection in your view file, but if it's really the thing you want to do, then you can do something like this:
(I assume you are using Opencart 2.x)

```
$wpbridge = new DB("mysqli", $hostname, $username, $password, $database);
$wpcontent = $wpbridge->query($sql);
```

Your `$wpcontent` variable will contain the (associatively) fetched result of the query.

Opencart is using an MVC(L) design pattern, and I would really recommend you splitting your code into these layers, as it's easier to debug and maintain.

Comment: I actually use OC 2. With this method, I get [different errors](https://gist.github.com/GizMecano/cec41cee2fd6c7c547a6#file-test-1). As you recommend splitting the code into MVC layers, do you suggest I should use another file than the template? I would prefer to not alter the core system.

Comment: Is the WP database on the same server...? Are you sure the database details are correct?

Comment: I think that you properly pointed my issue: WP and OC databases _aren't on the same server_ (but it'll be only during the development phase). I suppose I must migrate WP on local server to solve the issue or do you have any other suggestion?

Comment: No, but you have to make sure you are using the correct database details, hostname, port, and everything. You can include a port in the MySQLi instantiation just after the database part. For example: `$wpbridge = new DB("mysqli", $hostname, $username, $password, $database, $port);`